# Chinese reminder theorem - evaluating inverses

Tags: divisibility, chinese-remainder-theorem

So, this is the CRT scheme I know:

$$x=b_{1}*N_{1}*a_{1} + b_{2}*N_{2}*a_{2} + ...$$

Where $a_{x}$ is:

$N_{x}a_{x} \equiv 1 (mod $ $n_{x})$

---

All right, so let's assume I have the following system of congruences:

$$\begin{align} \begin{split} x &\equiv 3 \mod{10}\\ x &\equiv 4 \mod{7}\\ x &\equiv 2 \mod{9}. \end{split} \end{align}$$

$N_{1}=63$
$N_{2}=90$
$N_{3}=70$

---

**My question is -** if I get $10k-3$ as an inverse solution to the first congruence here...what should I substitute for k?

The website I got this example from substituted $k=1$, so $a_{1}=7$
The second inverse is $7k-1$, the website substituted $k=0$ this time, so $a_{2}=-1$

etc... I tried to substitute some random values, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What website and what explanation did they give? In general you can solve a system of linear congruences by using Euclid's algorithm.

Comment: http://math453spring2009.wikidot.com/lecture-8

Comment: Still not sure, what you're referring to. Where do they substitute random values that magically work? Also, the whole trick is calculating the multiplicative inverses. Once you have them, there is no more work to be done apart from substituting into your formula.

Comment: Well, I actually meant only evaluating multiplicative inverses...$63x \equiv 1 (mod 10)$ gives 7...why not -13, -3, 17, 27, ...?

Comment: Go back to the definition for multiplicative inverses: Multiplicative inverses are only defined $mod$ $n$, which particular element of the congruence class you take is irrelevant. However, it is standard to either take the minimum positive one (in this case $7, 6, 5$) or the one with minimum absolute value ($-3, -1, -4$). In the end it really only matters, which one you are most comfortable with and which one gives you the minimum amount of computation effort.